# Obtaining formula for roots of cubic equalation

Tags: field-theory

$f = t^3+pt+q \in \mathbb{C}(p,q)$
I want prove that splitting field of $f$ is
$$\mathbb{C}(p,q)[D,x]$$
$\mu_x = t^3-a$(over $\mathbb{C}(p,q)[D]$),$\mu_D = t^2-b$(over $\mathbb{C}(p,q)$).
I think that for $D = \sqrt{Disc(f)}$, therefore $\mathbb{C}(p,q)[D][t]/f(t)$ is splitting field, but $\mu_t = f$.
Also in my exercise i need to get formula for roots of $f$ from this information, but i have no ideas.